# How to convert this LEFT JOIN Linq Query to Lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq

How to convert this below left join linq query to lambda expression

```
var query = from e in db.Employee
join ed in db.EmployeeDetails on e.EmpId equals ed.EmpId into EmpIdInfo
from EmployeeDetails in EmpIdInfo.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
        EmpId = e.EmpId
       ,FirstName = e.FirstName
       ,LastName = e.LastName      
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between Employee and EmployeeDetails? Do Employee class contain property of type EmployeeDetail?  I ask this question because in your query you are not using `ed`varaible in the projection netiher EmpIdInfo.

Comment: relationship is 1-1 and they both relate with empId

Comment: Then you want to write a query that retrieve only employees that have EmployeeDetails, right?

Comment: no i want to retrieve the records from employee table which are not in employeedetails, which is left join basically

Comment: then this what to do `(db.Employee.Where(e => e.EmployeeDetails.EmpId == null).Select new
{
        EmpId = e.EmpId
       ,FirstName = e.FirstName
       ,LastName = e.LastName      
}).ToList();`

Comment: doesnt work lot of errors

Comment: `db.Employee.Where(e => e.EmployeeDetails.EmpId == null).Select(e => new { EmpId = e.EmpId ,FirstName = e.FirstName ,LastName = e.LastName }).ToList()` 
What is the error ? I rewrite the code :)

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'EmployeeDetails' and no extension method 'EmployeeDetails' accepting a first argument of type 'LeftJoinUsingLINQ_Lambda.Employee' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you please post the code of Employee and EmployeeDetails?

Comment: Nope. The C# code of your classes Employee and EmployeeDetail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95157/discussion-between-user1030181-and-codenotfound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all `Employee` that have not related data into `EmployeeDetails` without using Linq but with lambda expression you can write this code:

```
db.Employee.Where(e => e.EmployeeDetails.Any() == false).Select(e => new { EmpId = e.EmpId ,FirstName = e.FirstName ,LastName = e.LastName }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have correct relationship (FK) established between Employee and EmployeeDetails in the database and EF code generated properly with Navigation Properties available, the below solution should work.

If an employee does not have a corresponding record in EmployeeDetails, your Employee Object will have the embedded navigation property EmployeeDetails set to null. So, you should be good if you simple run the below:

```
db.Employee.Where(x => x.EmployeeDetails == null);
```

Please note I did not get into projecting any specific properties at this point as the above code will get you a list of such Employees that do not have their details in EmployeeDetails. Hence, this should work for you but you may choose to further filter the columns being projected using Select().

Please let me know if it worked for you...